# c# add Textbox dynamic

Tags: c#, web

I have  requirement like this.

I use ASP.NET to develop a web page.

Now I want to click button ,then add new textbox in page.
here is the part of code:

```
  <table with="900px">
    <tr>
        <td>
            Email :
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Add" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail0" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
             <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="[delete]" />
            <%--     the name should by txtEmail + <0,1,2,3,4..>--%>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="[delete]" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

the page like:

[image]

So how to finish this function **,also include use jquery or javascript to add new textbox**.

start ,i want to drag five textbox ,then hide it, if click add ,then show one textbox, if click **delete** ,then **hide** textbox. Is that a good solution?

**And the server side and client side both need to validate for textemail**

then this is need to associated the dynamic textbox.
can somebody help me with this?

Comment: It seems to me you just need to hook up the server-side click events for the buttons and do the work (i.e. remove the `tr`).

Comment: but is will refresh the page

Answer (score 1):

please go through the below code which i used in my application

```
function funAddElement(){
  var newTBDiv = document.createElement('div');
  document.getElementById("HdnBillDetailsCount").value = parseInt(document.getElementById("HdnBillDetailsCount").value) + 1;
        var count = document.getElementById("HdnBillDetailsCount").value;
        if (count >= 10) {
            return false;
        }
        newTBDiv.setAttribute('id', 'divBillDetails' + count);
        var billno = 'txtBillNo' + count;
        var amount = 'txtAmount' + count;
        newTBDiv.innerHTML = "<table width='100%' border='0' cellspacing='1' cellpadding='7' bgcolor='white' class='form_cont'> <tr> <td> BillNo </td> <td> <input type='text' value='' id='" + billno + "'/> </td><td>Amount:</td><td><input type='text' value='0.0'  ondrop='return false;' onpaste='return false;' oncut='return false;' oncopy='return false;' onkeypress='return numericOnly(this);' id='" + amount + "'/></td></tr></table>"
        divBillDetails.appendChild(newTBDiv);  
    }
```

divBillDetails is the div where in the first textbox.
here when u click on the button i called

```
OnClientClick="funAddElement();return false;"<br/>
```

this function adds textboxes to div till 10 and count of textboxes added is stored in HdnBillDetailsCount hidden control

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add textbox and button using C# in asp.net. Try as following

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
</div>
</form>
</body>
```

And the backend code is as following...

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox aTextBox = new TextBox();
        aTextBox.ID = "helloText";
        Button aButton = new Button();
        aButton.ID = "helloButton";
        aButton.Click += aButton_Click;
        aButton.Text = "helloButton";
        form1.Controls.Add(aTextBox);
        form1.Controls.Add(aButton);
    }

    void aButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Knockoutjs rocks:

```
    <script src="http:////cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.0.0/knockout-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout.mapping/2.4.1/knockout.mapping.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <asp:HiddenField ID="hfClientModel" runat="server" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var oViewModel;
        var iCounter;
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var oModel = JSON.parse($('#<%= hfClientModel.ClientID %>').val());
            iCounter = oModel.Items.length;
            oViewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(oModel);
            ko.applyBindings(oViewModel);
        });
        function DeleteEmail(iEmailIndex) {
            oViewModel.Items.remove(function (item) { return item.Index() == iEmailIndex; });
        }
        function AddEmail() {
            iCounter++;
            oViewModel.Items.push(ko.mapping.fromJS({ Email: '', Index: iCounter }));
        }
        function PersistClientModel() {
            $('#<%= hfClientModel.ClientID %>').val(ko.toJSON(oViewModel));
        }
    </script>
    <table width="900px">
        <tr>
            <td>
                Email :
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" data-bind="{value: FirstEmail}" />
                <input type="button" value="Add" onclick="AddEmail()" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <!-- ko foreach: Items -->
        <tr>
            <td>&#160;</td>
            <td>
                <input data-bind="{value: Email}" />
                <input type="button" value="Delete" data-bind="{click: function() { DeleteEmail($data.Index()); }}" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </table>
    <asp:Button Text="Postback!" ID="btnSave" runat="server" OnClick="btnSave_Click" OnClientClick="PersistClientModel()" />
```

Server side:

```
[DataContract]
public class ViewModel {
  [DataMember]
  public string FirstEmail { get; set; }
  [DataMember]
  public IList<EmailModel> Items { get; set; }

  public ViewModel() {
    Items = new List<EmailModel>();
  }
}

[DataContract]
public class EmailModel {
  [DataMember]
  public string Email { get; set; }
  [DataMember]
  public int Index { get; set; }
}

public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page {
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (!IsPostBack) {
      var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(ViewModel));
      using (var stream = new MemoryStream()) {
        serializer.WriteObject(stream, new ViewModel());
        hfClientModel.Value = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray());
      }
    }
  }

  protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(ViewModel));
    ViewModel viewModel;
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(hfClientModel.Value), false)) {
      viewModel = (ViewModel)serializer.ReadObject(stream);
    }
    // enjoy viewModel
  }
}
```